# Silverlight - Timeout Issue

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight 3 application that is querying a large dataset. This query is taking over one minute. After approx. one minute into the attempt, an error is getting logged into the event viewer that says:

"Membership credential verification failed"

Oddly queries that are taking shorter than 1 minute are running successfully. Because of this, I do not believe it is a "credential" issue, unless somehow it is expiring. But how do I set the expiration? I have no idea what else this could be.

Thank you,

Comment: are you talking to a WCF service?

Comment: Did the answer below end up working?

Answer (score 2):

Change the binding timeouts...
E.g.

```
<binding name="X" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00">
```

more here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx